# how to display a perfect 4k picture android TV?

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, television, android-tv

i have a task in my company. they want me to display a 4k resolution image (4096 X 2160) on the android TV that we are working now by only using Android java code. one thing that i to have mention is, our tv resolution is 1920 X 1080. i got this resolution from the log here:

```
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        TvLog.i(TAG, "Width" + display.getWidth());
        TvLog.i(TAG, "Height" + display.getHeight());
```

and the width will show 1920 while the height will show 1080. i just use a simple code to display the image. below is the code:

```
View view;
WindowManager wm;

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pict_4k, null);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END;
    wm.addView(view, params);
}
```

and the layout also simple which is:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/a1" >
```

i read that only at Android 6.0, 4k mode API will be introduced. currently im using Android 5.0. so, is there any way for me to force the picture show its actual resolution on the TV?

Answer (score 1):

Android TV resolution supports only up to 1080P

Yes, Android 6.0 does allow [4K display](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#4K-display), but only if hardware supports it.

> The platform now allows apps to request that the display resolution be
>   upgraded to 4K rendering on compatible hardware.